# When should vector/list be used?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structure

I can understand when to use lists, but I don't understand when it is better to use vectors than using lists in video games: when it is better to have fast random access ?

(And I understand why it's faster to insert/delete in lists because it just removes/adds pointers, but it still has to find the corresponding item...)

Comment: Re-added vector tag to this - if list is a valid tag, then vector is too.

Comment: Presumably vector was removed because it's used to mean mathematical vector, not std::vector.

Comment: how about nix them both and put `container`.

Comment: @Kylotan: It's as Joe said. This question was definitely about vectors, but it didn't belong with the vector tag.

Comment: So do we remove any ambiguous tag? That sounds like the wrong decision to me - better that your search turns up too much information than not enough. Skipping unwanted results is easier than brainstorming to find synonyms.

Comment: Even without the tag, this is still the third result when searching for vector. Tags are more for browsing and ignoring/highlighting than searching - ambiguity makes tags bad to use for those.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My rule of thumb, and I'm sure there will be debate on this, is to *never* use lists (unless you need to very, very frequently remove things from the middle of large lists).

The speed you'll gain by having all your elements in your container in contiguous memory (and therefore more cache-friendly) is worth the offset of the additional costs of adding/removing/resizing the vector.

Edit: Just to clarify a bit more, of course it should go without saying that any kind of "which is faster" question should be tested on whatever platform with whatever data sets are pertinent to your particular needs.  If I just need a collection of elements I just use vector (or deque, which is almost the same thing) unless there's a good reason *not* to.

Comment: I think it highly depends on your needs, if you never need to access a specific element and just need to read all of them and you add and remove elements frequently, the list is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some ammo to shoot on my classmates...

Comment: @Frédérick: That is the standard C++ wisdom, but it's also almost always wrong. Vectors, especially when dealing with vectors of pointers (which you almost always are for games), are extremely fast to remove stuff from the middle of - it is linear time, but it's a very very small overhead per item. It's also _much_ faster to iterate sequentially over a vector.

Comment: I can't say you are wrong, in fact I think it's right but still I don't think this only reason should swipe away lists definitely. Yes games do use a lot of vector pointers, but it can use containers on objects. For exemple a MapReader class that read each chunck of a binary map and store them in a vector. What if the map is loaded in an editor and the chunks are always modified, can't the list be a better choice ? I'm still a student, I worked on some commercialised games, but I have a lot to learn so tell me if I'm wrong, trying to answer questions is a nice way to learn myself :)

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of structure you're getting at exactly - this kind of optimization requires concrete examples to say anything definitively. For example, my first reaction to your use case would be an unordered set, which allows equally fast insertion, deletion, and lookup; in my experience sets are great for objects in editors. But as editors have much laxer real-time performance requirements - e.g. it's fine if responding to a "Delete" button press takes 1/20th of a second or takes a 1/2th of a second 10% of the time - this level of optimization also rarely applies to them.

Comment: @Frédérick Imbeault Modified isn't much of a problem it is Add\Remove that causes problems. From add\removed point to the end of the vector is copied to keep the vector contiguous.  If element order doesn't matter you can swap the deleted element with the last element then pop that for delete and add to the end for add.

Comment: I just came through a problem helping a student in his work and reminds me of a dangerous use of vectors. Imagine you have a vector of objects somewhere and other vectors of pointers, pointing on objects of the "Big" one. A student did this to create a sport simulation. He had a pool of players that could be transfered from teams, so teams pointed on players they had. The problem is, when you add objects to the big vector, it can reserve another array and copy elements. When that arrives... all pointers become bad. Maybe it's not quite well to do this, but it can bring errors hard to debug...

Comment: Well sure, taking the address of an element in a vector and storing that off isn't safe.  But generally speaking you hardly ever do that, instead preferring to have a vector of pointers of elements and copying the pointer around (or something similar).

Answer (score 8):

Use a list when iterator invalidation caused by modifying the middle of your data structure is going to cause a problem, or you need to keep your elements sorted so the swap and pop trick for quick middle collection deletes won't work and you have a large number of mid collection deletes.

You may also want to consider using a Deque.  It has similar performance characteristics to a vector but doesn't have vector's need for contiguous memory, and is a little more flexable.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to mention deques - you get the contiguous memory and lookup speed benefits of vectors, with fast insert/remove at both ends.

Answer (score 4):

Your choice should reflect your needs. All the elements of the vectors are continous in memory and lists has pointers to next / previous elements so they each have their advantage / disavantages :

Lists :

- Each elements takes 2 integers to point previous and next elements, so most commonly, that's 8 bytes more for each elements in your list
- Insert is linear in time : O(n)
- Remove is a constant operation : O(1)
- Access the x element is linear in time : O(n)

Vectors :

- Needs less memory (no pointers to other elements, it's a simple math algorithm)
- Remove is linear in time : O(n)
- Access the x element is constant : O(1) (That's because the elements are continious in memory so it's a simple math operation vectorPtr + ( x * bytesOfTheType ) )
- Insert can be in linear time, but most commonly, it's a constant operation : O(1) (That's because the vector in an array but always reserve 2 times it's capacity when the array is full so array copy is not frequent )

So list is better when you program needs to add and remove elements frequently, but never access (or rarely access) a particular element without the need of the others before. The vector should be used for better access time, but lacks effeciency when you need to remove or add elements.

Check this post on stackoverflow, it present a really nice graph with basic questions on your needs that drives you to a specific container depending on your answers :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366432/extending-stdlist

Comment: That graph really needs to start with a "Are you storing pointers and less than a thousand? No -> vector" node.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right, I did not consider the type stored it should also be analysed.

Answer (score 2):

Usually lists are used for structures like queues where there are lots of append and remove operations. **Example:** An ever changing list of entities that should be updated. The list itself only contains entities on screen and therefore changes frequently.

Vectors (or arrays) are better suited for a collection that doesn't change that much and where you need fast access to individual items within the collection. **Example:** A tile-map where you have to lookup tiles at a given index.

Tetrads opinion might be true, but it depends on the programming language that is used. I see that you tagged your question `c++`, but I tried to give an answer that isn't language-specific.

Comment: Well I might have also put C in it, but there aren't such containers in C, but that's something to think about: is there some STL-like tibrary for C ?

Comment: I've used glib (http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) in the past, which implements a number of standard data structures for C. I hated it because it's usually too verbose and desperately wants to be C++, but it's mature and stable.

Answer (score 0):

In console games we never, ever use std::list because:

1. it does memory allocations whenever you add a new item. memory allocations are slow.
2. it's full of pointers. pointers are bad. a pointer is a cache miss. a cache miss is bad.

even std::vector is losing favor on consoles because:

1. you often care only about, for example, the positions of all the objects. like for example you want to collide the objects with each other, in which case you don't care what their color is. so you want all the positions to be contiguous in memory and you want the colors to be somewhere else far away, to avoid polluting the cache. but std::vector requires you to store everything for each object in a contiguous chunk of memory (e.g. position then color.) so if you do work that reads only the positions, you need to read all the colors into the cache too, even if you don't use them. this is wasteful.

Comment: @bmcnett "[] .. but std::vector requires you to store everything for each object in a contiguous chunk of memory" - that's not a question of the container, its a question of your data-layout, you can have all position in a continuous chunk of memory with a std::vector: `struct point{float x, y, z, w}; std::vector<point> positions;`

Comment: my school are going to love this :)

Comment: -1 because this answer doesn't add anything to the list vs. vector discussion already here, and its claim about vector polluting the cache is wrong, as Maik says.

Comment: you misunderstood my claim. i never said that *among all the containers* std::vector is particularly guilty of polluting the cache. all the containers, and in fact even arrays, are about equally guilty of that. std::vector is falling out of favor *because C++ objects themselves* are falling out of favor. C++ mandates that each object's data be contiguous in memory. you can get around that by avoiding C++ objects, for example by using std::vector<position> as mentioned above.

Comment: Except `point` is a C++ object (as is `std::vector`, as is something as simple as `float`). I know the distinction you're trying to draw, but you're doing a bad job of explaining it.

Comment: The problem is not so much objects per se, but object members (which float does not have.) It is cache-hostile for the members of a single object to be contiguous in memory, as required in C++ for a[i] to be equivalent to *(a+i). What is better is for the first members of N objects to be adjacent, followed by the second members of N, where N relates to cache size. Games are slowly moving toward this goal in an ad hoc manner.